# Sending Data to 2 MySQL tables - FuelPHP / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fuelphp

I am adapting [StationWagon](https://github.com/abdelm/stationwagon) (FuelPHP app) and so far it's working really well.

I have adapted it (with some help) to allow multiple images to be uploaded to the server. This is also working great.

**However**, I am thinking it would make more sense if I had **2 Tables**: **1) Articles** and **2) ArticleImages**. I would use a Foreign Key to associate the Images with the Article. So when publishing an article it would add the article data to 'Articles' table and move each image to a new row in 'ArticleImages'.

So ultimately my **'ArticleImages'** table could be:

> ID | ImageURL | ArticleID

Portion of my '**articles.php**' controller:

```
<?php       

    public function action_add()
    {
    $val = Model_Article::validate('add_article'); //<-- maybe its just me but i never saw any similar to this in fuelphp sorry about this if im wrong

    // if your form validation is okay than continue with everyhing else
    if ($val->run())
    {
        $article = Model_Article::forge();
        // Custom configuration for this upload
        $config = array(
            'path' => DOCROOT.DS.'images',
            'randomize' => true,
            'ext_whitelist' => array('img', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'),
        );

        Upload::process($config);

        // if a valid file is passed than the function will save, or if its not empty
        if (Upload::is_valid())
        {
            // save them according to the config
            Upload::save();

           //if you want to save to tha database lets grab the file name
            $value = Upload::get_files();  

            foreach($value as $files) {
               print_r($files); 
            }
            $article->filename = $value[0]['saved_as'];
         } 

        $status = (Input::post('save_draft') ? 0 : 1);

        if ( ! $val->input('category_id'))
        {
            $category_id = null;
        }
        else
        {
            $category_id = $val->validated('category_id');
        }

             $article->user_id = $this->user_id;
             $article->category_id = $category_id;
             $article->title = $val->validated('title');
             $article->body = $val->validated('body');
             $article->published = $status;


        if ($article->save())
        {
            Session::set_flash('success', 'Article successfully added.');
        }
        else
        {
            Session::set_flash('error', 'Something went wrong, '.
                'please try again!');
        }

        Response::redirect('articles/add');
    }

    $this->template->title = 'Add Article';
    $this->template->content = View::forge('articles/add')
        ->set('categories', Model_Category::find('all'), false)
        ->set('val', Validation::instance('add_article'), false);
    }

/* End of file articles.php */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when i made the code for you back a few days a go you only requested, one file input.

And no offense but you are doing it all wrong...

```
    foreach($value as $files) {
      print_r($files); 
    }
 $article->filename = $value[0]['saved_as'];
```

should be

```
foreach($value as $files) {
           $articleimg = Model_Articleimages::forge();
           $articleimg->image_row_name = $files['saved_as']
        }
```

To get you to understand

what you did here, `$value = Upload::get_files();` yes this gets all the elements but since you need to loop trouh the elements you dont need it

Second

this `$value[0]['saved_as']` only grabs the first image name, just the first one, and since you are in a loop now you need to refer to the `$files` variable as i shown you in the above example, **just an example**

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to make a relation between Articles and ArticleImages. An ArticleImage belongs to an Article, while an Article has many ArticleImages. FuelPHP has functionality built in for what you are trying to achieve. Have a look at the [FuelPHP docs on its Object Relational Mapper](http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/relations/intro.html), especially the Belongs To and Has Many relations.